# List of supported browsers

Tags: silverlight-3.0, cross-browser

Can someone help me where can I get a list of browsers supported by Silverlight "3.0"?
Silverlight 3.0 doesn't work over Chrome and many more... want to know the supported list for "3.0"

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Silverlight#Compatibility